# Aggregate function works in printing, but raises error when assigning it to a value

Tags: python, pandas

I am applying some simple statistics on a data set. I have read the data by pandas. I want to count the number of counties for each state. I have made state the index of my data frame and am looping through it by using the unique values of the index and counting the counties. When I print the values in my loop it gives me the result followed by an error 'count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)', but when I assign the value of count(), it raises  'count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)'.

```
df_aux = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV']==50]
df_aux.set_index('STNAME', inplace=True)
index_list = df_aux3.index.unique().tolist()
```

index_list is the list of all states. I use it for looping in my auxillary data frame as follows:

```
county_list = []
state_list = []
for item in index_list:
    df_aux3.loc[item,'CTYNAME'].count()
    county_num = df_aux3.loc[item,'CTYNAME'].count()
    county_list.append(county_num)
    state_list.append(item)
dict_aux={'State':state_list,
         'county_num': county_list}
```

Line

```
df_aux3.loc[item,'CTYNAME'].count()
```

causes following error:

```
TypeError: count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

However, when I use print in my loop it returns values correctly as well as raising error! By using print I mean the following code:

```
for item in index_list:
    print(df_aux3.loc[item, 'CTYNAME'].count())
```

The df_aux3 data frame is as shown:
[image: image of data frame]

The result shown by printing count() which is correct in princilple together with the error raised are shown below:

[image: esult of applying print to count()]

Moreover when I use

```
df_aux3.loc['Alabama', 'CTYNAME'].count()
```

it works perfectly well with no error! I don't understand its behavior.
I was wondering is it due to lazy evaluation. If it is why it is behaving in this way and how I can fix it?

Thank you very much for your attention and support.

Comment: could it be that you have a NaN somewhere in your dataframe?

Comment: @KenHBS oh, it is possible, especially that it stopped at a specific record. But more importantly why count() works for a specific value like df_aux3.loc['Alabama', 'CTYNAME'].count() but when I use it in for loop it raised error? Besides aggregate functions as I read ignore NaN values, right?